# Calendar Manipulation to only the cells with a Date

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, dom-events

I have a basic calendar that I got from here http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex7/basiccalendar_dev.htm
I want to modify the calendar by adding an svg image to only the cells that have a date in them.

I commented the line in the JavaScript where i think needs manipulation. Its the 5th line from the bottom. I tried adding an Id to the 'td' on that line but that affected the cells that don't have dates in them as well.

What needs to be done in order to isolate the cells that have a date in them? Any ideas? Appreciate any help.

JavaScript

```
var todaydate = new Date()
var curmonth = todaydate.getMonth() + 1 //get current month (1-12)
var prevmonth = todaydate.getMonth() - 1 //get current month (1-12)
var curyear = todaydate.getFullYear() //get current year

document.write(buildCal(curmonth, curyear, "main", "month", "daysofweek", "days", 1));

function buildCal(m, y, cM, cH, cDW, cD, brdr) {
    var mn = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var dim = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];

    var oD = new Date(y, m - 1, 1); //DD replaced line to fix date bug when current day is 31st
    oD.od = oD.getDay() + 1; //DD replaced line to fix date bug when current day is 31st

    var todaydate = new Date() //DD added
    var scanfortoday = (y == todaydate.getFullYear() && m == todaydate.getMonth() + 1) ? todaydate.getDate() : 0 //DD added

    dim[1] = (((oD.getFullYear() % 100 != 0) && (oD.getFullYear() % 4 == 0)) || (oD.getFullYear() % 400 == 0)) ? 29 : 28;
    var t = '<div class="' + cM + '"><table class="' + cM + '" cols="7" cellpadding="0" border="' + brdr + '" cellspacing="0"><tr align="center">';
    t += '<td colspan="7" align="center" class="' + cH + '">' + mn[m - 1] + ' - ' + y + '</td></tr><tr align="center">';
    for (s = 0; s < 7; s++) t += '<td class="' + cDW + '">' + "SMTWTFS".substr(s, 1) + '</td>';
    t += '</tr><tr align="center">';
    for (i = 1; i <= 42; i++) {
        var x = ((i - oD.od >= 0) && (i - oD.od < dim[m - 1])) ? i - oD.od + 1 : '&nbsp;';
        if (x == scanfortoday) //DD added
            x = '<span id="today">' + x + '</span>' //DD added
        t += '<td id="CellDate" class="' + cD + '" >' + x + '</td>';//// this is where the date values appear in the cells, this is where we need to insert the svg
        if (((i) % 7 == 0) && (i < 36)) t += '</tr><tr align="center" >';
    }
    return t += '</tr></table></div>';
}
```

CSS

```
    .main {    
        border:0em solid black;
        height:80%;
        left: 2.5%;
        opacity:.9;
        position:fixed;
        top:17%;
        width:95%;  
    }
    .month {
        background:#D5273E;   
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #D5273E, #0096dd);
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #D5273E, #0096dd);
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #D5273E, #0096dd);
        background:      -o-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #D5273E, #0096dd);
        background:         linear-gradient( to left bottom, #D5273E, #0096dd);
        border-radius:0.2em;
        color:#000000;
        font:bold 30px verdana;
        height:1.5em;


    }
    .daysofweek {
        background-color:#404040;   
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #161616, #404040);
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #161616, #404040);
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #161616, #404040);
        background:      -o-linear-gradient( to left bottom, #161616, #404040);
        background:         linear-gradient( to left bottom, #161616, #404040);
        border-radius:0.2em;
        color:#ffffff;
        font:bold 1.5em verdana;  

    }
    .days {
        background-color: lightblue;
        background-image: url("../Images/Rectangle.svg");
        background:lightblue;   
        background: -webkit-linear-gradient( to left bottom, lightblue, white);
        background:    -moz-linear-gradient( to left bottom, lightblue, white);
        background:     -ms-linear-gradient( to left bottom, lightblue, white);
        background:      -o-linear-gradient( to left bottom, lightblue, white);
        background:         linear-gradient( to left bottom, lightblue, white);
        border-radius: 0.2em;
        color:black;
        font:bold 1.6em verdana;  
        padding: 0.1%;
        position: relative;
        text-align:left;
        vertical-align:top; 
    }
    .days #today{
        background-color:#0096dd;
        border-radius:0.2em;
        color: red;
        font-weight: bold;
        padding: 0.2%;
        text-align:center;   
    }
    #CellDate{
        background-image: url("../Images/Rectangle.svg");
    }

    #CalendarBox{
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-position:center center;
        background-size: 100% 100%, auto;
        border: solid black 0.1em;
        border-radius:.3em;
        height:4em;
        left:20%;
        position:absolute;
        top:5%;
        width: 6em;

}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
   <?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
   <meta charset="UTF-8" content="HTML,CSS,XML,JavaScript">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
   <title>Safety Incident Calendar</title>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <meta name="description" content="Fullscreen Background Image Slideshow with CSS3 - A Css-only fullscreen background image slideshow" />
   <meta name="keywords" content="css3, css-only, fullscreen, background, slideshow, images, content" />
   <meta name="author" content="Codrops" />
   <script src="Scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/Global.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/modernizr.custom.86080.js"></script>
   <script src="Scripts/calendar.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/Design.css" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/SlideShow.css" />
</head>
<body id="page">
   <center>
      <h1 class="safetyScreenHeader">Safety Incident Calendar</h1>
      <h3 id ="calendarText">Number of Days since the last incident:</h3>
      <div id="safetyValueTV" >45</div>
      <div id="safetyheaderIcon"></div>
      <div id="tv1clock"></div>
   </center>
      <object data="Images/Rectangle.svg" type="image/svg+xml" id="CalendarBox" />
</body>
</html>
```

SVG

```
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
     <path d='M0 0 L0 63 L100 0 ' fill='#FF0000' />
     <text x="2" y="13" fill="blue">Day</text>
     <path d='M100 0 L0 63 L100 63 ' fill='#98FB98' />
     <text x="40" y="60" fill="blue">Evening</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

I needed to re-write the 5th line from the bottom on the JavaScript page to ...

```
t += (x != "&nbsp;"  ? '<td id="CellDate" class="' : '<td class="') + cD + '" >' + x + '</td>';
```